# Image div class and margin class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for the following mark-up and adding in my own classes of css where needed to style the pages how they are required

```css
.sm-margin {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="menu.php">
                        <img src="img/turkey.jpg" alt="Turkey dinners" style="width:100%">
                        <div class="caption text-center sm-margin">
                            <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Check out our menu</button></p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am unclear to why the .sm-margin doesn't add the small margin at the top - see it in effect on my website [here](http://adonnelly759.students.cs.qub.ac.uk/cms/)

Comment: It already affected, what are you expect?

Comment: Does work for me (Firefox and Chrome) - what makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: If you notice - The marign is added in your website. [this](https://screenshots.firefox.com/MkjKa4zmfRIAmblg/adonnelly759.students.cs.qub.ac.uk)  the yellow faded line

Comment: I can see the css working fine. What do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: if you look at the site: http://adonnelly759.students.cs.qub.ac.uk/cms/ ... between the image and the button it does not add the margin-top

Comment: Working fine for me too. Firefox and Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: @DerekNolan I am using Chrome, however it works fine for me on my Firefox browser, it seems my chrome browser isn't updating the page for me, this is my vision from [chrome](https://imgur.com/a/H8PEb) compared to my [Firefox browser](https://imgur.com/a/hc4LK). So very strange why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

The margin is added to the top of your button in the website
U can inspect and un check the checkbox of your class to see the difference if u use that css class or not...

Answer (score 0):

My code was correct, it was a browser error. I cleared my cache on the Chrome browser and it corrected it.

Thanks all for input.